# python: module 'Crypto.Cipher.AES' has no attribute 'MODE_CCM' even though pycrypto installed

Tags: python, package, pycrypto

pycrypto is installed (when I run `pip list` one of the result is `pycrypto (2.6.1)`)

and it works but when I would like to use the `MODE_CCM` it returns: `module 'Crypto.Cipher.AES' has no attribute 'MODE_CCM'`

My Python version: `Python 3.5.2 :: Anaconda 4.2.0 (x86_64)`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

according to https://gist.github.com/jbdatko/7425443 the newest version of pycrypto does not have the CCM mode.

I solved the problem by installing `pip install pycryptodomex` and replacing the `Crypto` package with`Cryptodome`

after installing:

in your python code
replace `from Crypto.Cipher import AES`
with  `from Cryptodome.Cipher import AES`

Answer (score 5):

By using python 3, i solved it by installing **pycryptodome** (`pip3 install pycryptodome`).
 *No need to replace **Crypto** by **Cryptodome***

Answer (score 1):

You can use `dir(AES)` to see the list of supported `MODE_xxx`.