# AssertionError - Creating my own python library and I am getting an assertion error

Tags: python, unit-testing, aes, python-unittest

I am coding an encryption library that allows you generate either symmetric or asymmetric key/key pair and use it within Either of these 4 classes: `TextEncA`, `TextEncS`, `ImageEncA` and `ImageEncS`. The code looks to be syntactically correct however while testing the code I am getting an error with the testing of the `TextEncS` class using unittest - namely an assertion error.

Here is the code for testing the `TextEncS` class:

```
class TestTextEncS(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.message = b"This is a test message"
        self.key = tienc.generate_key_s()
        self.text_enc = tienc.TextEncS(self.key)

    def test_encrypt_decrypt(self):
        ciphertext, tag = self.text_enc.encrypt(self.message)
        result = self.text_enc.decrypt(ciphertext, tag)
        self.assertEqual(self.message, result)

    def test_decrypt_failure(self):
        wrong_key = os.urandom(32)
        ciphertext, tag = self.text_enc.encrypt(self.message)
        self.assertRaises(Exception, self.text_enc.decrypt, ciphertext, tag, wrong_key)
```

Here is the code for the `TextEncS` class itself:

```
class TextEncS:
    """ symmetric text encryption """

    def __init__(self, key):
        self.key = key

    def encrypt(self, plaintext):
        cipher = AES.new(self.key, AES.MODE_EAX)
        ciphertext, tag = cipher.encrypt_and_digest(plaintext)
        return ciphertext, tag

    def decrypt(self, ciphertext, tag):
        cipher = AES.new(self.key, AES.MODE_EAX, tag)
        return cipher.decrypt(ciphertext)
```

The key for the symmetric keys are generated as follows:

```
def generate_key_s():
    key = os.urandom(32)
    return key
```

And the error as seen in the terminal is presented like this:

```
======================================================================
FAIL: test_encrypt_decrypt (Test_TIENC.TestTextEncS)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\*****\Desktop\tienc\tests\Test_TIENC.py", line 38, in test_encrypt_decrypt
    self.assertEqual(self.message, result)
AssertionError: b'This is a test message' != b'\x1c\x83\x8cJ\xa7\x1b\x02g\xfet\xf1XOP\x9c\xa6\xa8\x99k\xabC\x01'

----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

How would I go about solving this issue and what should I try?

I have tried changing the code about have read up on the documentation however nothing I have tried seems to have worked.

Comment: Assertion error just means the test is not passing, aka your encryption/decryption is not working correctly.

Comment: @matszwecja yeah I understand that, what I'm getting from the error is that the decryption is not working properly however I'm a bit lost on how to fix this.

Comment: Are you certain there will be an Exception raised if you pass wrong key? Kinda doesn't make sense when you think about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Modifications to your class `TextEncS`

You have to modify your production code as below:

```
from Cryptodome.Cipher import AES

class TextEncS:
    """ symmetric text encryption """

    def __init__(self, key):
        self.key = key

    def encrypt(self, plaintext):
        cipher = AES.new(self.key, AES.MODE_EAX)
        ciphertext, tag = cipher.encrypt_and_digest(plaintext)
        return ciphertext, tag, cipher.nonce

    def decrypt(self, ciphertext, tag, nonce):
        cipher = AES.new(self.key, AES.MODE_EAX, nonce)
        data = cipher.decrypt_and_verify(ciphertext, tag)
        return data
```

The modification are:

1. `encrypt()` that return 3 values (I have add `chiper.nonce`)
2. `decrypt()` that has 3 arguments (I have add `once`); furthermore the body of `decrypt()` is a bit different from your code

In your question you have not include the `import`. In my code the import is:

```
from Cryptodome.Cipher import AES
```

### Modifications to your test code

The test code is modified accordly (see the comments inside the code):

```
class TestTextEncS(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.message = b"This is a test message"
        self.key = tienc.generate_key_s()
        self.text_enc = tienc.TextEncS(self.key)
    
    def test_encrypt_decrypt(self):
        # encrypt() return ---> ciphertext, tag, nonce
        ciphertext, tag, nonce = self.text_enc.encrypt(self.message)
        # pass 3 arguments to decrypt()
        result = self.text_enc.decrypt(ciphertext, tag, nonce)
        self.assertEqual(self.message, result)

    def test_decrypt_failure(self):
        # encrypt() return ---> ciphertext, tag, nonce
        ciphertext, tag, nonce = self.text_enc.encrypt(self.message)
        wrong_key = os.urandom(32)
        # create a new instance the class TextEncS with the wrong key
        self.text_enc = tienc.TextEncS(wrong_key)
        # change a bit the test
        with self.assertRaises(Exception):
            self.text_enc.decrypt(ciphertext, tag, nonce)
```

### Useful links

For details about Encrypt data with AES see [this documentations](https://pycryptodome.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/examples.html).

To know why I have use `Cryptodome` instead `Crypto` module see [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43987779/python-module-crypto-cipher-aes-has-no-attribute-mode-ccm-even-though-pycry).

Comment: I am using the pycryptodomex library that is independent from the pycryptodome and crypto libraries as far as I'm aware, would this make any difference to the code you have suggested? Additionally would it be better to switch to pycryptodome?

Comment: @Vey I have only use `Cryptodome` I'm not able to give you this kind of suggestion. I'm sorry. I think that my code can crypt and decrypt with AES and pass your tests. With Crypto I can't compile my code so I have used `Cryptodome`.

Comment: @Vey The code with my modification is useful for you? Can you use it to crypt and decrypt or it doesn't work? About the test: I have used the context manager to check the Exception raised and not your sintax. With your sintax the test, in my opinion is not correct. Give me a feedback please.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply - I was pretty busy the last few days. Adding `nonce` and other modification as per your provided code solved the issue. Thank you very much!